# Возможно ли создать пресет\шаблон для раскраски ячеек

Tags: excel, office

Мне нужно каждый раз проделывать одну и туже операцию: ПОИСК -> НАЙТИ ВСЁ -> выделить все найденные результаты -> сделать заливку

Можно ли создать пресет\шаблон который применится к новому файлу или создать один файл и вставлять туда новые столбцы, и чтобы применялось условие раскраски ячеек к новым ячейкам

[b]вот готовый файл с раскрашенными ячейками
[image: скриншот]

**РЕШЕНИЕ:  код под макросы excel:**

```
Sub ВыделитьДубликатыРазнымиЦветами()
On Error Resume Next
' массив цветов, используемых для заливки ячеек-дубликатов
Colors = Array(12900829, 15849925, 14408946, 14610923, 15986394, 14281213, 14277081, _
               9944516, 14994616, 12040422, 12379352, 15921906, 14336204, 15261367, 14281213)

Dim coll As New Collection, dupes As New Collection, _
    cols As New Collection, ra As Range, cell As Range, n&
Err.Clear: Set ra = Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
If Err Then Exit Sub

ra.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone: Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each cell In ra.Cells ' запонимаем значение дубликатов в коллекции dupes
    Err.Clear: If Len(Trim(cell)) Then coll.Add CStr(cell.Value), CStr(cell.Value)
    If Err Then dupes.Add CStr(cell.Value), CStr(cell.Value)
Next cell
For i& = 1 To dupes.Count ' заполняем коллекцию cols цветами для разных дубликатов
    n = n Mod (UBound(Colors) + 1): cols.Add Colors(n), dupes(i): n = n + 1
Next
For Each cell In ra.Cells ' окрашиваем ячейки, если для её значения назначен цвет
    cell.Interior.Color = cols(CStr(cell.Value))
Next cell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: Добро пожаловать на SO! Два цвета для "первый/второй", два для "чётное/нечётное", еще два для "тм/тб" и для "BTSD/x"? Насчёт фиолетового E2:F7 не понятно. Ну, похоже, это четыре условных формата по значению ячейки... Или макрос на событие "содержимое листа изменилось"

Comment: @JohnSUN Не могли бы пояснить что такое "SO"? я уже прогуглил все варианты и не нашёл что-то что пересекалось бы с моей проблемой. Вы всё правильно поняли, фиолетовое выделение можно опустить

Comment: *SO* - `Stackoverflow`. ресурс, где Вы разместили вопрос. ===А стоит ли красить? Пожалейте свои глаза. Для зрения такой наляпистый попугай - не лучшая картинка. А второе - работа с цветом в Excel затратная. Условное форматирование грузит книгу. Если макросом красить - медленно, да и перезапуск заливки при изменении  данных... Анализировать данные можно другими способами - строить сводные таблицы, макросом извлекать нужные данные...

Comment: нашёл код для макроса excel: